# At a round table there are 5 gentlemen and 5 ladies. If ladies and gentlemen are to sit in alternate seat.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

At a round table there are 5 gentlemen and 5 ladies. If ladies and gentlemen are to sit in alternate seats, in how many ways can they sit (in a circular arrangement)?. Im having trouble figuring out this problem, but I believe I'm on the right track. Their are 10 people and because its a circle you have to minus out one, now split into men and women so it !4/0! * !4/0 * 2.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference  This is a tutorial in using MathJax on this site.

Answer (score 1):

First guy has $10$ seats to choose from.

Remaining guys have $4!$ ways to sit in their $4$ chairs.

There are $5!$ ways of seating the $5$ women in the remaining $5$ chairs

$10\cdot 4! \cdot 5! = 28800$ ways

Comment: By convention I believe we divide by however many chairs in the circle there are (in this case $10$).

Comment: Could you explain why?

Comment: I believe the reason is because if you rotate the table, you will see that every possibility has been counted 10 times, due to a circle having no end.

Comment: But a rotation of the people is still technically a different seating arrangement

Comment: Hey, that's why it's a convention, not fact :)